# Asset catalog image slicing in Spritekit

Tags: xcode, storyboard, sprite-kit, skspritenode, asset-catalog

I want to make my button horizontaly and vertically stretchable.

In the storyboard everything is okay

[image: storyboard image]

But in SpriteKit is not the same!

I'am loading the image using

```
let spriteTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "button");
let sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: spriteTexture, color: nil, size: CGSizeMake(290, 400));
```

[image: spritekit image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If centeRect, yScale, xScale are set the button will streach properly

```
let sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: spriteTexture, color: nil, size: CGSizeMake(290, 58));
sprite.position = CGPointMake(0, -100);
sprite.centerRect = CGRectMake( 140/290.0, 24/58.0, 10.0/58.0, 10.0/58.0);
sprite.yScale = CGFloat(250.0 / 58.0);
sprite.xScale = CGFloat((self.frame.size.width - 20) / 290.0);

self.addChild(sprite);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set your sprite's `centreRect` property that defines how it is scaled. This is a normalised `CGRect` in the centre that will not be scaled but the elements around it will be.

Looking at your button you want everything but the centre few pixels to remain unstretched. To set the `centreRect` property:

```
sprite.centerRect = CGRectMake(0.49, 0.49, 0.02, 0.02)
```

This means that a rectangle is drawn from a point 49% of the width and height away from the corner of the sprite and has sides of length 2% of the sprites width and height respectively. Therefore only the centre 2% of the texture is stretched.

This is discussed in the "Working with Sprites" document that Apple provides and explains it far more effectively that I just did under the section "Resizing a Sprite":

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Sprites/Sprites.html

Comment: Yes I set **centerRect** but still the button was not ok, in order to make it work **yScale** should also be set.